# Displaying Webcam using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I tried to interface Webcam using OpenCV 3.1 in Ubuntu.
My program is as follow.

```
void main(){

    VideoCapture camera(0);
    Mat frame;

    while(true){
        camera >> frame;
        imshow("test", frame);
        int key = waitKey(10);
        if(key == 27){
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Devi
ce '/dev/video0' cannot capture at 1280x720
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /home/nn/Softwares/opencv/opencv/modules
/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 818
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/nn/Softwares/opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.
cpp:818: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer
```

Comment: What if you try to open the device using a path, as in `VideoCapture camera("/dev/video0');` Where does the error occur? When you create the camera object or when you try to read the frame? What about setting it to lower resolution before you attempt to grab images?

Comment: @DanMašek, the error happens at the line VideoCapture camera(0); The same thing happens when I replace with VideoCapture camera("/dev/video0"); Let me try with lower resolution.

Answer (score 1):

here is a golang repo using OpenCV 4+ which runs webcam and other opencv toys just fine on Ubuntu 19.10 and golang 1.13.4

```
//  https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv

package main

import (
    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main() {
    webcam, _ := gocv.OpenVideoCapture(0)
    window := gocv.NewWindow("Hello")
    img := gocv.NewMat()

    for {
        webcam.Read(&img)
        window.IMShow(img)
        window.WaitKey(1)
    }
}
```